# Preventing dependent property validation when the parent property does not exist

Tags: jsonschema

I am new to JSON schemas. I have a property (property1) that is dependent on another property (property2), which in turn is dependent on a third property (property3).  I am trying to figure out how to prevent the schema from validating property1 if property2 doesn't exist.  I am using the Python jsonschema module for validating.

I have a simple schema with three properties: species, otherDescription, and otherDescriptionDetail.  The rules I'm trying to enforce are:

1) if species = "Human", otherDescription is required.

2) if species = "Human" and otherDescription != "None", otherDescriptionDetail is required.

3) if species != "Human", neither of the other two fields is required.

My test JSON correctly fails validation if species is "Human" and otherDescription doesn't exist, but it also reports that otherDescriptionDetail is a required property even though at this point it shouldn't be because there is no otherDescription value to compare it against.  Is it possible to implement this logic with a JSON schema?

This is my schema:

```
"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "$id":"http://example.com/test_schema.json",
  "title": "annotations",
  "description": "Validates file annotations",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "species": {
      "description": "Type of species",
      "anyOf": [
        {
          "const": "Human",
          "description": "Homo sapiens"
        },
        {   
          "const": "Neanderthal",
          "description": "Cave man"
        }
      ]
    },
    "otherDescription": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "otherDescriptionDetail": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "species"
  ],
  "allOf": [
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "species": {
            "const": "Human"
          }
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "required": ["otherDescription"]
      }
    },
    {
      "if": {
        "allOf": [
          {
            "properties": {
              "species": {
                "const": "Human"
              },
              "otherDescription": {
                "not": {"const": "None"}
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "then": {
        "required": ["otherDescriptionDetail"]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

My test JSON is:

```
{
  "species": "Human"
}
```

The output that I want:

```
0: 'otherDescription' is a required property
```

The output that I am getting:

```
0: 'otherDescription' is a required property
1: 'otherDescriptionDetail' is a required property
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to defined `otherDescription` as a required property insilde `allOf`. Otherwise `allOf` block will pass even if `otherDescription` not available.

```
"if": {
  "allOf": [
     {
       "properties": {
          "species": {
             "const": "Human"
          },
          "otherDescription": {
             "not": {"const": "None"}
          }
       },
       "required": ["otherDescription"]
     }
   ]
},
"then": {
   "required": ["otherDescriptionDetail"]
}
```

Comment: Given there's only one schema inside your `if`, you don't need to wrap it in `allOf`.

Comment: The schema is actually larger, I only posted a section of it because the other sections are similar.